# Application got crashed : request permission after upgrading app to compileSdkVersion 33/ Android 13

Tags: flutter, dart, android-permissions

Package Used : [permission_handler: ^10.0.0](https://pub.dev/packages/permission_handler)

**app/build.Gradle**

```
compileSdkVersion 33
minSdkVersion 24
targetSdkVersion 33
```

**android/build.gradle**

```
kotlin_version = '1.7.10'
```

Permission added in AndroidManifest.xml

```
  <uses-permission
         android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"  tools:ignore="ScopedStorage" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_INTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_IMAGES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_VIDEO" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
```

Crash log on click allow or denied permission

```
E/AndroidRuntime(13312): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(13312): Process: com.app.example, PID: 13312
E/AndroidRuntime(13312): java.lang.AssertionError
E/AndroidRuntime(13312):    at io.flutter.plugins.firebase.messaging.FlutterFirebasePermissionManager.onRequestPermissionsResult(FlutterFirebasePermissionManager.java:33)
E/AndroidRuntime(13312):    at io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterEngineConnectionRegistry$FlutterEngineActivityPluginBinding.onRequestPermissionsResult(FlutterEngineConnectionRegistry.java:777)
E/AndroidRuntime(13312):    at io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterEngineConnectionRegistry.onRequestPermissionsResult(FlutterEngineConnectionRegistry.java:409)
E/AndroidRuntime(13312):    at io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivityAndFragmentDelegate.onRequestPermissionsResult(FlutterActivityAndFragmentDelegate.java:757)
E/AndroidRuntime(13312):    at io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterFragment.onRequestPermissionsResult(FlutterFragment.java:915)
E/AndroidRuntime(13312):    at io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterFragmentActivity.onRequestPermissionsResult(FlutterFragmentActivity.java:549)
E/AndroidRuntime(13312):    at android.app.Activity.dispatchRequestPermissionsResult(Activity.java:8833)
E/AndroidRuntime(13312):    at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:8663)
E/AndroidRuntime(13312):    at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:5857)
E/AndroidRuntime(13312):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:5903)
E/AndroidRuntime(13312):    at android.app.servertransaction.ActivityResultItem.execute(ActivityResultItem.java:54)
E/AndroidRuntime(13312):    at android.app.servertransaction.ActivityTransactionItem.execute(ActivityTransactionItem.java:45)
E/AndroidRuntime(13312):    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
E/AndroidRuntime(13312):    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
E/AndroidRuntime(13312):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2438)
E/AndroidRuntime(13312):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
E/AndroidRuntime(13312):    at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:226)
E/AndroidRuntime(13312):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:313)
E/AndroidRuntime(13312):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8663)
E/AndroidRuntime(13312):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(13312):    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:571)
E/AndroidRuntime(13312):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1135)
I/Process (13312): Sending signal. PID: 13312 SIG: 9
```

Permission request code

```dart
Future<PermissionStatus> requestStoragePermission() async {
  return Platform.isAndroid ? Permission.storage.request() : Permission.photos.request();
}
```

Comment: same issue......

Comment: You can check issue here as its there on their github page : https://github.com/Baseflow/flutter-permission-handler/issues/907

Comment: In a git hub, the issue is for getting the wrong status after allowing the permission and In my case, APK is crashed on the result. @HardikMehta

Comment: Then its related to flutterfirebase : check it here : https://github.com/firebase/flutterfire/issues/9430. @SheetalGhori

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This issue was caused because of firebase_messaging: 13.0.0

Upgrading all packages related to firebase will resolve this crash issue on permission.

[image]

```dart
  firebase_core: ^1.22.0
  firebase_auth: ^3.8.0
  firebase_messaging: ^13.0.1
  firebase_dynamic_links: ^4.3.7
```

Issue closed in Github:

https://github.com/firebase/flutterfire/issues/9430
https://github.com/firebase/flutterfire/issues/9429

Answer (score 0):

On my end, the issue was caused by requesting notification permission with  `firebase_messaging: ^13.0.0`

After upgrading to  `firebase_messaging: ^13.1.0`, the app stops to crash